# syncevt.changeList[cl].name sometimes is "clear" instead of "success"

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I use shared object to drawing line.

But sometimes `syncevt.changeList[cl].name` is "clear" insted of "success" and value of setproperty become undefined.

Have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

see the [livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/events/SyncEvent.html#changeList). either the object has been deleted, or alternatively it has fallen out of synch. use the SyncEvent.SYNC event to resynch.